# Mapping occurrence count based on criterion from CSV in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, dataframe

I have a CSV with numerous columns, there's only two columns I'm concerned with, they are 'Text field (Environment/s Affected)' and 'Text field (Rating)'.

The environment column has entries like dev, test, prod. The rating column has entries like P1, P2, P3, P4, P5.

I need to somehow map out how many occurrences each of the environments has had. What would be the best way to do this in Python?

The end goal would be something like this:
P1/P2 in Test: 15
Total in Test: 30
P1/P2 in Staging: 24
Total in Test: 30

P1/P2 would be an aggregate of those, Total would be an aggregate of the others, i.e. P3, P4, P5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have tagged your question with `pandas`, so I assume your data is already in the form of a `DataFrame`. If so, the following command should do:

```
df.groupby(['env', (df['rating'].isin(['P1', 'P2']))]).size().rename(index={True: 'P1/P2', False: 'Total'}, level=1)
```

(This assumes that your `DataFrame` is named `df` and that your "Environment/s Affected" and "Rating" columns are named `env` and `rating` respectively.)

This performs a grouping across first unique values of the `env` column, and then the `rating` column, depending on whether the value contained in it is either 'P1' or 'P2', or not. It then counts the number of rows within each subgroup.

If your data is not yet in the form of a `DataFrame`, you will need to load it as one from a CSV, which can be done with the following command:

`df = pd.read_csv(file_path)`

You may need to tweak the arguments a little, depending on the format of your file; the document can be found [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html).

Comment: Hi Marcus,    

Thanks! It's displaying everything as required, however if there are no Ratings for the environment, it won't display anything. How could I get it to add a 0 to the occurrences if none are detected for the environments?

It currently displays as:
Env1 Others P3+ 11  
Env2 Others P3+ 1
Env3 Others P3+ 4  

I'd like:
Env1 Others P3+ 11
Env2 Others P3+ 1
Env3 Others P3+ 4
Env1 P1/P2 0
Env2 P1/P2 0
Env3 P1/P2 0

Comment: @Govno I think I get what you mean, but could you edit your question and specify the expected output for clarity?

Comment: (or, actually, maybe you should ask a new one. I'm not sure.)