# Pandas groupby output is not displaying null values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to map out occurrences of values based on two columns. It's working great, thanks to Marcus in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54611708/mapping-occurrence-count-based-on-criterion-from-csv-in-python). However, I'd also like it display a 0 for the incidents which have no count (where the rating field is null). It currently ignores null values.

Current output is:
[image]

As you can see, there's no occurrences for Critical, so they're not showing. I need it to display a 0 if there's no occurrences for those environments/ratings in the dataframe.

The output I'd like is:
[image]

Basically, I'd like Ratings (such as Critical and Others P3) to always show, so that even if there are no entries for Critical or Others, it'll display as 0 for that environment.

Here's the current code:
`csvfile = pd.read_csv("rawstats.csv", encoding = "ISO-8859-1", usecols=['Environment/s Affected', 'Rating'])`
`df = pd.DataFrame(csvfile)`
`df.groupby(['Environment/s Affected', (df['Rating'].isin(['1', '2']))]).size().rename(index={True: 'Critical', False: 'Others P3+'}, level=1).to_csv('summary.csv')`

Sample data:
`Rating,Environment/s Affected
3,Env1
3,Env1
3,Env1
3,Env2
3,Env2
3,Env2
3,Env2
3,Env3
3,Env3
3,Env3
3,Env3
3,Env3
3,Env4
3,Env4
3,Env4
3,Env4
3,Env4
3,Env4
4,Test5
4,Test5
4,Test5
4,Test5
4,Test5
4,Test5
4,Test5
,Env1
,Env1
,Env3
,Env4
,Env1`

Thanks!

Comment: It is better show us some sample data

Comment: I'm not sure, but you might get what you want if you do .fillna(0) on your dataframe before doing the groupby

Comment: Tried .fillna(0) but it's made no difference, unless I can somehow expand the .rename condition to include 0.

Comment: Ok, I now understand the problem better. Sorry, I don't know how to help you efficiently, but one idea that might not be very elegant is to generate a combination dataframe (grouping only with Environment, and each having 2 rows (Other and Critical) then you can use merge with the output, filling the missing values with 0 on the merge).. Sorry if it's not helpful

Answer (score 0):

groupby won't show NaN values, you need to replace them a dummy values first:

```
In [11]: df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4], [pd.np.nan, 6]], columns=["A", "B"])

In [12]: df
Out[12]:
     A  B
0  1.0  2
1  3.0  4
2  NaN  6

In [13]: df.groupby("A").mean()  # no nulls
Out[13]:
     B
A
1.0  2
3.0  4
```

For example, you might use -1:

```
In [14]: df.replace({"A": {np.nan: -1}}).groupby("A").mean()
Out[14]:
      B
A
-1.0  6
 1.0  2
 3.0  4

In [15]: df.replace({"A": {np.nan: -1}}).groupby("A").mean().reset_index().replace({"A": {-1: np.nan}})
Out[15]:
     A  B
0  NaN  6
1  1.0  2
2  3.0  4
```

Answer (score 0):

You need [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) by `MultiIndex` by all combination of unique values of first level of `MultiIndex` by [`MultiIndex.from_product`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html):

```
s = (df.groupby(['Environment/s Affected', 
                 (df['Rating'].isin(['1', '2']))]).size()
       .rename(index={True: 'Critical', False: 'Others P3+'}, level=1))
print (s)
Environment/s Affected  Rating    
Env1                    Others P3+    6
Env2                    Others P3+    4
Env3                    Others P3+    6
Env4                    Others P3+    7
Test5                   Others P3+    7
dtype: int64

mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df['Environment/s Affected'].unique(),
                                 ['Others P3+', 'Critical']],
                                 names=['Environment/s Affected','Rating'])
print (mux)
MultiIndex(levels=[['Env1', 'Env2', 'Env3', 'Env4', 'Test5'], ['Critical', 'Others P3+']],
           codes=[[0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4], [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]],
           names=['Environment/s Affected', 'Rating'])

df1 = s.reindex(mux, fill_value=0).reset_index(name='counts')
print (df1)
  Environment/s Affected      Rating  counts
0                   Env1  Others P3+       6
1                   Env1    Critical       0
2                   Env2  Others P3+       4
3                   Env2    Critical       0
4                   Env3  Others P3+       6
5                   Env3    Critical       0
6                   Env4  Others P3+       7
7                   Env4    Critical       0
8                  Test5  Others P3+       7
9                  Test5    Critical       0
```

If need `Critical` in last rows add [`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html):

```
df1 = (s.reindex(mux, fill_value=0)
        .sort_index(level=[1,0], ascending=[False, True])
        .reset_index(name='counts'))
print (df1)
  Environment/s Affected      Rating  counts
0                   Env1  Others P3+       6
1                   Env2  Others P3+       4
2                   Env3  Others P3+       6
3                   Env4  Others P3+       7
4                  Test5  Others P3+       7
5                   Env1    Critical       0
6                   Env2    Critical       0
7                   Env3    Critical       0
8                   Env4    Critical       0
9                  Test5    Critical       0
```